# How to create a user in a meteor.js through the react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm trying to create a user from the reaction of component:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base'

import { createContainer } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

import { FlowRouter } from 'meteor/kadira:flow-router';
import { mount } from 'react-mounter';

FlowRouter.route('/signup', { name: 'signup', action(){ mount( SignUp ); } });

AccountsTemplates.configure({
   forbidClientAccountCreation: false
});

class SignUp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { mail:'', pass:''};
  }
  handleMailChange(e){ this.setState({mail: e.target.value}); }
  handlePassChange(e){ this.setState({pass: e.target.value}); }
  eSignup(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Sign Up Form submitted.");
    Accounts.createUser({ email:'mail', password:'passwd'}, (err)=> {
      if (err) console.error(err.reason);
      else {
        console.info('Create user success !');
        FlowRouter.go('/');
      }
    });
  }
  render(){
    return (
        <div className="row">
          <div className="container">
            <form name="login">
              <input type="email" name="mail" onChange={this.hMailChange.bind(this)}/>
              <input type="password" name="Pass" onChange={this.hPassChange.bind(this)}/>
              <input type="submit" value="Signup" onClick={this.Signup.bind(this)}/>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But I get an error: `403 Signups forbidden`.
I looked at the source code of the component the meteor. And maybe I find there the lines generating the error:
https://github.com/meteor/accounts/blob/master/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js#L1014

```
if (Accounts._options.forbidClientAccountCreation)
   return { error: new Meteor.Error(403, "Signups forbidden") };
```

And I don't understand why this test works if I set `Accounts._options.forbidClientAccountCreation` like `false`

`account-ui` and other packages to work with `ui` and `users` I deleted.

My `package.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.18.0",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "lib": "^1.0.5",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.0",
    "particles.js": "^2.0.0",
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-mounter": "^1.2.0"
  }
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code must have set [`forbidClientAccountCreation`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsCommon-config) to `true` somewhere. You need to turn that option to `false` in order to create user in client.

```
import { AccountsCommon } from 'meteor/accounts-base'

AccountsCommon.config({
  forbidClientAccountCreation: false
});
```